# Javascript HTML5 change icon for fa-play

Tags: javascript, html

I added a audio(autoplay) on my website.
Actually I want to pause and play the music, 
the icon should also toggle at the same time to `fa-play`.

This is my HTML markup:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleSound() {
        var audioElem = document.getElementById('player');
        if (audioElem.paused)
            audioElem.play();
        else
            audioElem.pause();
    }

</script>
```

```html
<li>
    <a class="fa fa-pause" id="player" type="button"
  onclick="javascript:toggleSound();">
        <span>Play/Pause</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

```html
<audio autoplay id="player" src="embrace.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: Ok so what's your question?

Comment: `id` should be unique. Your `<a>` and `<audio>` tags should have different `id`s. Ivan's answer will then work (presuming he updates with the `id` of the anchor tag).

Comment: I want to do that to the click on the button class fa - pause change to fa-play

Answer (score 2):

You can complete your JS with this:

```
<script>
    function toggleSound() {
       var audioElem = document.getElementById('player');
       if (audioElem.paused) {
          audioElem.className = "fa fa-play";
          audioElem.play();
       } else {
          audioElem.className = "fa fa-pause";
          audioElem.pause();
       }
    }
</script>
```

**Edit:**
If you want that function called when you perform the click you should bind the function to the event `click`. There are several ways, but the easiest is like this:

```
<a class="fa fa-pause" onclick="toggleSound()" >
```

You can do it in whatever DOM element, not only in `<a>`, this was only an example.

Comment: added a comment to OP - his audio tag and anchor tag have the same `id`. I thought it was awkward the link would have its class changed then ... play/pause.

Comment: Nice, that's true, and very important! :)

Comment: I want to do that to the click on the button class fa - pause change to fa-play

Comment: @OskarBurulcich Check edit

Comment: Thanks!! I do it!! :)

Comment: @OskarBurulcich If it solved the question, you should mark it as accepted